# Are c++11 lambda targets statically created?

Tags: c++11, lambda

I have a following method:

```
using async_handler_t = std::function<void(boost::system::error_code, std::size_t)>;
async_handler_t deadlineHandler(boost::system::error_code &ec) {
    return [&ec, this](boost::system::error_code newEc, std::size_t) {
        ec = newEc;
        deadline_.cancel();
    };
}
```

This is simple asio deadline handler which stops the deadline timer and allows the io_service-run loop to continue (grabbed this from official asio timeout docs).

The question is about how much times the function itself is generated. I understand, that I return a functional object from this method (std::function object) which is created dynamically during runtime but is the target function created only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lambda expression implicitly declares a functor class, and creates an instance of it.
The generation of the class' type (and the code of its `operator()`) is, of course, done once at compile-time.
A new instance of this class (containing what the lambda captured) *is* created each time you call your function.

Answer (score 1):

The code inside the body of the lambda will only be compiled once and all instances of that lambda's closure object type will share the code. But each call to `deadlineHandler` will result in a new instance of the closure type being created, its members `ec` and `this` being initialised, and then a `std::function` object being created from that instance.